# Rest API Matrix param annotation

Tags: java, rest, postman

I have a class called InjectDemoResource in which I have created a method `getParam()` which is as below[image]

As you can see I have set the path to `/injectdemo` and `/annotations`, I used the the `@MatrixParam` annotation in the `getParam()` method.

I am using Rest API client - Postman in which i typed the URL in the following way:

```
http://localhost:8080/Messenger/webapi/injectdemo/annotations:param=value
```

But I got the following error : `404 Not Found`
[image]

Comment: Use `;` instead of `:`.

Comment: Try using this URL http://localhost:8080/Messenger/webapi/injectdemo/annotations;param=value

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. Do not post code as images!

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code when asking a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `;` instead of `:` in the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/Messenger/webapi/injectdemo/annotations;param=value
```

For more details, on how matrix params work, check the [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.7):

> [**3.2.7.  Path-Style Parameter Expansion: {;var}**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.7)
>
> Path-style parameter expansion, as indicated by the semicolon (`;`)
> operator [...], is useful for describing URI
> path parameters, such as `path;property` or `path;name=value`. [...]

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the error.

```
http://localhost:8080/Messenger/webapi/injectdemo/annotations;param=value
```

Make sure that you are placing a `semicolon ( ; )` in your URI after `/annotations`